# Ubuntu login loop. Cannot fix

Tags: login

My system recently had a problem, where I could not update the system because it kept on saying :

```
> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource
 temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to lock the administration
directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?
```

So I followed [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process) steps and removed the lock file. After a reboot, I cannot login. Its stuck in loop. I have already tried many answers on this forum like changing ownership of .Xauthority and even removing it. But nothing works, its still stuck in a loop.

Help me!

Comment: You can try access it by command line (ALT + 1, ...., ALT + 6 ), login as your user, if you can do it, then it's a window manager issue, create another user, then diff between your user home dir, and the fresh user and copy over the defaul files. Also before doing that, make a backup of your home dir with rsync, `rsync -avz /home/yourUser/ /some/other/path/`

Comment: I have two questions: 1) the "steps" you mention is a post with 14 answers(!). *Which* of the steps did you follow? What is the exact commandline you used to remove the lock?
2) What exactly do you mean with "its stuck in loop". Please say exactly what you see on screen.

Comment: 1. I followed the first answer. I deleted the lock file. 2. Stuck in loop, like if I enter my password at the login purple page, it wont login to home, it just flashes and again login page appears.

Comment: just FYI, error message before you removed the lock file that said Could not lock blah..blah.. is another process using it, it means some program use administration priviledge task in background (usually you couldnt access sudo apt update, upgrade, etc). just wait a few seconds or minutes until the background task finished, then try again. just don't panic yet.

Comment: and for login loop, you could try this [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: accepted answer is exactly what I have tried. But it didnt help :|